# How to create several different policies with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to create a several different policies this is my code:

This is my main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
count = length(var.name) != [] ? length(var.name) : 0
name = var.name[count.index]
path = var.path
description = var.description
policy = jsonencode(var.policy[count.index])
```

This is my variables.tf

```
variable "policy" {
description = "The policy in IAM (tpl file)"
type = list(any)
default = []
}

variable "name" {
description = "The name of the policy"
type = list
default = []
}
```

And for examples my var.tfvars

```
policy = [policy1,policy2]
```

This is the error

```
Error: Invalid value for module argument
│
│ on main.tf line 14, in module "test":
│ 14: policy = var.policy
│
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "policy" defined at ../policy/variables.tf:19,1-18: all list
│ elements must have the same type.
```

Comment: What is the error or problem? What do you need help with? So far you have posted a statement, not a question.

Comment: Error: Invalid value for module argument
│
│ on main.tf line 14, in module "test":
│ 14: policy = var.policy
│
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "policy" defined at ../policy/variables.tf:19,1-18: all list
│ elements must have the same type.

Comment: there is more to that ... your error shows module, but your code has no module, but that error is crystal clear `Invalid value for module argument` you are passing an invalid value `all list elements must have the same type.`

Comment: As per community guidelines: "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." Please don't add critical details as comments, edit the original question to include all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach that code you posted:

```hcl
variable "policies" {
  description = "The policies in IAM"
  type = map(object({
    path = string
    description = string
    file = string
  }))

  default = {
    "foo": {path : ".", description : "", file : "foo.json"},
    "bar": {path : ".", description : "", file : "bar.json"}
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "role_policy" {
  for_each    = var.policies
  name        = each.key
  path        = each.value.path
  description = each.value.description
  policy      = file( each.value.file)
}
```

You can see that now the variables are all in one
with `type = map(object({`
We can loop over that, and that is exactly what I do in the resource:
`for_each    = var.policies`
*and of course the default in my code is just an example*

---

I strongly recommend against `type = list(any)` that could makes the next developer what type is the list in use:
...and error looks straight forward:
`Invalid value`
`all list elements must have the same type.`